# Linear programming - optimality conditions

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

From Bertsimas intro to linear optimization - exercise 3.7:

Consider a feasible solution x to a standard linear program:

\begin{align*}
  \min\quad        & \textbf{c'x}                                                        \\  \text{subject to } & \textbf{Ax=b} \\
   & x \geq 0 \ \\
\\
                    \text{And let }   & Z = \{i | x_i=0\}                                            
                                                        &   
                   &   
\end{align*}

Show that x is an optimal solution if and only if the linear program:

\begin{align*}
  \min\quad        & \textbf{c'd}                                                        \\  \text{subject to } & \textbf{Ad=0} \\
   & d_i \geq 0, \ i \in \{Z\} \\
\\
                    \                                            
                                                        &   
                   &   
\end{align*}
Has an optimal value of zero.

I understand that for two solutions of the original program, x and y, we can define d=y-x. Then Ad=0 and probably it relates to the optimally condition of c'd>=0. But I still don't understand how it relates to the Z set and how to prove the direction from 2->1

Comment: This is a corollary of Exercise 3.2 and 3.3. See here: https://math.solverer.com/library/dimitris_bertsimas/introduction_to_linear_optimization/exercise_3-7?utm_source=stackexchange.com&utm_medium=link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $$c'x = c'y + c'(x-y),$$ where $y$ is also a solution of the LP. Let $$d = y - x.$$ Clearly, $Ad = 0$, and $ d_i \geq 0, \ i \in \{Z\}$.

Now, if the second LP has minimum value of $0$, this means that $$c'd \geq 0. $$ Hence, $$c'x \leq c'y,$$ and the result is proven.

Conversely,  take $d$ solution if the second LP. Define, $$y = x + \epsilon d.$$ Clearly, $Ay = b$, and it is possible to find $\epsilon$ such that $y \geq 0$. As $x$ is optimal, this implies $c'd \geq 0$, and obviously $0$ is reached for $d = 0$.